# Date Format - C# - Conversion

Tags: c#, excel, date, datetime

I extracted data from a Database to Excel, the date columns are expressed in this format.

**38876,588587963**

I am now trying to read this file in C# and convert dates into DateTime format. Can someone enlighten me on this date format.

When i try to create a DateTime object the software throw an error.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("38876,588587963");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time-formatted column in excel to C# DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358275/convert-time-formatted-column-in-excel-to-c-sharp-datetime)

Comment: How about DateTime.FromOADate(38876.588587963) == 08/06/2006 14:07:34 ?

Comment: How did you read the values from Excel? Libraries like EPPlus or the OLEDB driver would return a DateTime value if the cell's format style was set to a Date or Time related style

Comment: How are you reading this value? Are you for instance doing a .ToString() where you don't need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it into a `DateTime` by using the `FromOADate` method in `DateTime`. However, that method accepts a double which doesn't work with the current formatting, parse it as a `double` and set the culture settings like this:

```
string output = "38876,588587963";
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(output, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Or if you know the culture is going to always be `fr-CA` you can do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(output, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA")));
```

Comment: @RufusL I have just updated my answer. You are correct using `CultureInfo` is a better way of doing it.